# Code generation using preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, class, macros, code-generation

Lately, I am working in a project, that has a lot of code that is being generated using macros. I have come across such situation where generated code was very less. But in this current one there is a lot of code that is being generated using #defines etc. 
Example, like a class for event generation and processing and generating class Id's for class.

```
#define INIT_EVENT_INFO(eventType) \
   template <> const GenericClassID eventType::tClassID(#eventType) ;

#define DECLARE_EVENT(dType, evtType, destnType) \
   typedef DUMMY_EVT_GEN<dType, std_event, custom_destn, destnType>::EventClass evtType;

template <typename ctData,
          EventTypes evType,
          DestnTypes evtDestType = standard_destn,
          class DestnInterface = EmptyClass>
class DUMMY_EVT_GEN
{
private:
   // alias for our current generator
   typedef DUMMY_EVT_GEN<ctData,
                              evType,
                              evtDestType,
                              DestnInterface> Generator;

   // Construct the first layer by adding the data part to our
   // framework event base class.
   //
   typedef BaseEvent::DerivedEvent<Generator> CompleteEvent_;


   /*
    * Assemble an event destn type
    */

   // Determine base class for event Destn: RTTIEventDestn for
   // rtiDestns
   typedef typename IF<isRtiDestn, BRTTIEventDestn, EventDestn>::type DestnBase_;

   // create event Destn type
   typedef typename IF<isCustomDestn, DestnInterface, BaseEvent::THBDestn<Generator> >::type DestnType_;

public:

   /**
    * A struct that contains all configuration options 
    */
   struct Config
   {
      /// base class for the Destn (rti or not)
      typedef DestnBase_  DestnBaseClass;
      /// class serving as data container for the event type
      typedef ctData     EventDataClass;

      /// the resulting event type
      typedef CompleteEvent_ EventClass;
      /// the resulting Destn interface type
      typedef DestnType_  DestnInterface;
   };

   // our final return values
   typedef typename Config::EventClass EVT;
   typedef typename Config::DestnInterface DestnInterface;
   typedef typename Config::EventClass EventClass;
};
```

Now, my question is, Is there a specific way that already defines such things.

**Hash defines can be used at one's own liberty.** 
But, are there any defined patterns or ways to write such a code, which helps us generate such code. Not only this scenario. There are many other scenarios, where such a code can be written and used for auto generation of classes, events, structures etc.

As a programmer, how to think of writing such macros' which will ease our effort. It does comes by practice, but are there any specific ways or patterns 
 or any documents which helps us to program this way, I mean to think of programming using such macros.

Any pointers or suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: For C++ there is boost that provides this. If you are really interested in that for C, you could look into my package P99.

Comment: in this particular case the macros are used to pollute the code :-(. The program would be better without them. Though there are good reasons for using macros in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

this is just my thought which does not fit in the simple reply :-).
C++, in particular c11 and up added a lot of features to replace macros with a controllable compiler-based generators, starting with template, ending with constexpr. This is a much more powerful mechanism then macros, though it usually requires more text to express the intent. Anyway, for this reason a need in marcros, compared to `c` is significantly reduced. I see actually 3 good reasons for using them with c++

1. hiding implementation-specific details in the language. i.e. function or struct attributes in gcc, which might not be implemented in other compilers or implemented differently. `#define PACKED __attribute((packed))__`
2. using conditional compilation for different reasons, like guard macros in header files: `#ifndef MY_HDR .. #define MY_HDR ... #endif`
3. convenience macros, replacing relatively big chunks of repeated code which does not fit well in a function, in particular when you need to convert something to a string. i.e. `#define tostr(A) case A: return #A;`

Comment: Thanks surge for your answer. I definitely got the advantages of using such macros. But is there any specific pattern or any definitive coding or usage guide of macros that helps learn this style of coding and apply it everywhere else. I have seen such code in windows event generation mechanism too. But here most of the code is generated using such macros. I just wanted to know under what circumstances such macros should be used and are there any specific pattern that could be followed for the same.

Comment: The advice is: do not use macros unless you **absolutely** need them. Not sure if there is a better guideline :-). You would probably find some organization-specific guidelines, but no industry-wide. I guess the only thing everyone agrees on (more or less) is on the capital NAMES of the macros. The rest is personal.

Comment: Thanks Sere for your inputs.

Comment: What I hate about macros and templates is that the tools routinely break when displaying code that is instantiated in several places, and there is no workaround about it.